# Support Multidex Android studio Below 5.0

Tags: android, android-studio

Multidex: Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Answer (score 0):

By adding below line will solve this issue.

```
    dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.+'
     }
```